# Блок, закреплённый под блоком

Tags: html, css, javascript

Как прикрепить блок к низу основного блока, чтобы использовать его в качестве селектора изменения размера основного блока?

Как [здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/altescape/McGH6/).

[image: qeqqe]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здравствуйте.

А это дело можно в **CSS** сварганить, прописав простой параметр

```
bottom: -5px;
```

Comment: Спасибо, не получалось, потому что основной блок был "float: right", а прикрепляемый left.